# Maximizing an angle on a circumference

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Given two points $A, B$ within a circle $\Gamma$, how can I find a point $P$ in the circumference such that the angle $\widehat{APB}$ is maximum?

I know that $P$ is the point where a circle through $A$ and $B$ just touches $\Gamma$, but I cannot construct this either.

I have draw the situation in geogebra:
https://www.geogebra.org/m/uWQv2SCy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the problem boils down to finding a circle through $A,B$ that is tangent to the original circle $\Gamma$. For starters, let $Q$ be the intersection between $\Gamma$ and the perpendicular bisector of $AB$. If we perform a circle inversion with respect to the circle $\Xi$ centered at $Q$ through $A$ and $B$, $\Gamma$ is mapped into the line $\gamma$, with $\gamma$ and $AB$ meeting at $R$. We have to find a circle that is tangent to $\gamma$ and goes through $A,B$: for such a purpose, we may exploit the secant-tangent theorem. Let $RT$ a tangent to $\Xi$ and $U,V$ the points on $\gamma$ such that $RU=RV=RT$. The intersections between $\Gamma$ and $QU,QV$ are the wanted tangency points, and they belong to the circle centered at $R$ with radius $RT$.

[image]